# Canopy Relief Ratio (Grid Metrics) FUSION/LDV

Tags: lidar, forest-ecology, fusion

According to the paper cited below, CRR tells us about the shape of trees and is defined as:

Canopy Relief-Ratio (CRR) is a quantitative descriptor of the relative shape of the canopy from altimetry observation (Parker and Russ, 2004; Pike and Wilson, 1997), defined as mean height returns minus the minimum height divided by the maximum height minus the minimum height. This ratio reflects the degree to which canopy surfaces are in the upper (> 0.5) or in the lower (< 0.5) portions of the height range.

Reference

Parker, G. G., & Russ, M. E. (2004). The canopy surface and stand development: assessing forest canopy structure and complexity with near-surface altimetry. Forest Ecology and Management, 189(1-3), 307-315.

In `Fusion`, this can be computed using `GridMetrics`, my question is, for example, if the CRR is `0.6474`, how can I interpret the shape of the canopy with this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the shape of trees, it is the variation of the canopy (relative surface morphology). The higher the CRR the more local variation occurs in the canopy (eg., open canopy) whereas small values represent less variation (eg. closed or uniform age canopy). Because of all of the different possible canopy configurations and the influence of the defined scale, there is no single interpretation of a given value thus, CRR is a relative measure of canopy variation and technically represents rugosity.

This metric is just a repackaging of Pike's geomorphometric Surface Relief Ratio (SSR) and is derived such: `(mean(x) - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))` where; x is a matrix of some NxN window (in the case of CRR, canopy heights).

Comment: Can vegetation type be identified with this metric, if so are there any ratio ranges that could depict whether the vegetation is either coniferous, deciduous or a shrub? Or should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: I do not think that CRR alone could reliably discriminate vegetation type. However, CRR used in conjunction with other lidar derived metrics have been shown to discriminate vegetation type very well, sometimes better than spectral data; see Hudak et al., 2006 "Regression modeling and mapping of coniferous forest basal area and tree density from discrete-return lidar and multispectral satellite data". For additional lidar metrics (used in FUSION) see; Evans et al., 2009 "Discrete Return Lidar in Natural Resources: Recommendations for Project Planning, Data Processing, and Deliverables".